# Lambda Expression to filter pair of same number

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, .net-core

I have the table that record the in and out of item.

```
 Id    Name Status Created
 1     A1   1      9/11/2018 14:00:00 <- 1
 2     A1   1      9/11/2018 14:01:00 <- 2
 3     A1   1      9/11/2018 14:02:00 <- 3
 4     A2   1      9/11/2018 14:03:00 <- 4
 5     A3   1      9/11/2018 14:04:00 <- 5
 6     A1   0      9/11/2018 14:05:00 <- consider 1 is taken out.
 7     A1   1      9/11/2018 14:06:00 <- 6
```

I wanna filter the pair; index 1 and index 6, from table. And leave me with items with status 1. The correct table should be like the following

```
 Id    Name Status Created

 2     A1   1      9/11/2018 14:01:00 <- 2
 3     A1   1      9/11/2018 14:02:00 <- 3
 4     A2   1      9/11/2018 14:03:00 <- 4
 5     A3   1      9/11/2018 14:04:00 <- 5

 7     A1   1      9/11/2018 14:06:00 <- 6
```

but my lambda expression to filter items with status 1

```
public class Item {
   public int Id;
   public string Name;
   public bool Status;
   public DateTime;
}
var Items = new List<Item>();
// This give me everything
Items = await db.items.Where(i => i.Status == true).ToListAsync();
```

I got the list of every item with status 1

```
 Id    Name Status Created
 1     A1   1      9/11/2018 14:00:00 <- 1
 2     A1   1      9/11/2018 14:01:00 <- 2
 3     A1   1      9/11/2018 14:02:00 <- 3
 4     A2   1      9/11/2018 14:03:00 <- 4
 5     A3   1      9/11/2018 14:04:00 <- 5

 7     A1   1      9/11/2018 14:06:00 <- 6
```

How do I apply lambda expression to filter out a pair with same name to be removed from my list? I want to know any shortcut with lambda expression to filter such list?

Examples:

```
 Id  Name Status DateTime             Id Name Status DateTime
  6  A1   0      9/11/2018 14:05:00   1  A1   1      9/11/2018 14:00:00
  // this id 1 and id 6 i want to remove based on name and date time
                                      2  A1   1      9/11/2018 14:01:00
                                      3  A1   1      9/11/2018 14:02:00 
                                      4  A2   1      9/11/2018 14:03:00
                                      5  A3   1      9/11/2018 14:04:00
                                      7  A1   1      9/11/2018 14:06:00
```

Comment: OrderBy Created descending.  Then use Group by name and then take first results. var results = db.items.OrderByDescending(x => x.Created).Group(x => x.Name).Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault()).ToList();

Comment: Can you explain why only ID 1 should be filtered out? It is not a "pair" with the closest date. Or do you mean you want to filter the earliest entry if multiple entries have the same name?

Comment: @Sweeper, I want to a pair with earliest date time to be removed first.

Comment: Can this logic be applied with lambda expression ?

Comment: I am very confused by what you are doing. Can you explain why ID 1 and 6 should be removed? ID 6 doesn't have the earliest date out of all entries with name A1. Shouldn't ID 1 and 2 be removed then?

Comment: @Sweeper, they are repeated items and let say another log with name A1 and status 0 means remove two 'A1' from the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
// your original data
var Items = new List<Item>();

// those items with status 0
var itemsToBeRemoved = Items.Where(x => !x.Status);

// remove those first
Items.RemoveAll(itemsToBeRemoved.Contains);

// now find the things with the same name, order by date, get the first one.
var theOtherItemsToBeRemoved = itemsToBeRemoved.Select(x => 
    Items.Where(y => y.Name == x.Name).OrderBy(y => y.Created).FirstOrDefault()
).ToList();

// now remove the items found
Items.RemoveAll(theOtherItemsToBeRemoved.Contains);
```

Comment: I like this answer more than others for its simplicity and easy to add on. I tested the other answer and make me a bit confused on first try esp setting up the lookup table.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any LINQ extension method, that matches your requirement, but you could easily achieve it with nested loops, as following:

```
  // Data generation
  var items = new List<Item>();
  for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    items.Add(new Item() { Id = i + 1, Dt = DateTime.Parse("9/11/2018 14:00:00").AddMinutes(i), Name = "A1", Status = true });
  items[3].Name = "A2";
  items[4].Name = "A3";
  items[5].Status = false;

  // It's also good to make sure that elements are in correct order
  items = items.OrderBy(i => i.Dt).ToList();

  // Procedure, to execute your logic
  for (int i = 0; i < items.Count(); i++)
  {
    // If it has Status = true, then look for "enclosing" element with Status = false
    if(items[i].Status)
      for (int j = i + 1; j < items.Count(); j++)
      {
        if(!items[j].Status && items[j].Name == items[i].Name)
        {
          // Mark items, so we delete them (and recognize those with status 0 as used)
          items[i].Name = "";
          items[j].Name = "";
        }
      }
  }
  // Remove all marked elements
  items.RemoveAll(i => i.Name == "");
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about LINQ-to-Entity expression, but after loading items in the memory you can remove items which is "marked" as removed in the database.

```
var items = await db.items.OrderBy(item => item.Created).ToListAsync();

var stillInItems = items.GroupBy(item => item.Name)
                        .Select(group => group.ToLookup(item => item.Status))
                        .SelectMany(lookup => 
                        {
                            var outItemsCount = lookup[false].Count();
                            return lookup[true].Skip(outItemsCount);
                        })
                        .ToList();
```

I think it would be possible to do in the SQL as well - play with `ROW_NUMBER` for items with same name and status and then exclude items which have correspondent item with same `ROW_NUMBER` but status = 0.

Answer (score 0):

Using LINQ, you can group by `Name`, then count the number of `Status` `0` and then return all the `Status` `1` skipping count of `Status` `0` objects ordered by `Created`. If there are more `0` than `1`, none are returned for that `Name`.

```
var filtered = src
                .GroupBy(s => s.Name)
                .SelectMany(g => { // for each name group
                    var skipCount = g.Where(r => r.Status == 0).Count(); // count the 0 status
                    return g.Where(r => r.Status == 1).OrderBy(r => r.Created).Skip(skipCount); // return the 1 status without earliest matched to 0 status
                })
                .OrderBy(s => s.Id);
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you only want to remove the first occurrences with both a Status true and Status false per name I guess this would be viable:

```
// Create lookup
ILookup<string, Item> lookupItems = Items.OrderBy(ordBy => ordBy.Created)
                                         .ToLookup(l => l.Name);

// Iterate through your collection
Items.RemoveAll(item => lookupItems[item.Name].Any(lookupItem => !lookupItem.Status)
     ? lookupItems[item.Name].First(lookupItem => !lookupItem.Status).Id == item.Id || 
       lookupItems[item.Name].First(lookupItem => lookupItem.Status).Id == item.Id
     : false);
```

Comment: This will not work when collection have more than one item with status = 0 for same name.

Comment: It will only remove the first Status 1 with the first Status 0 indeed, the other entries for that name remain untouched